# Parsing JSON files using org.json

Tags: java, android

How do i parse a JSON that is like this?

```
[{
    "id" : 28010942,
    "type" : "trafficlight",
    "title" : "225 - Shaw Blvd. / Gomezville - Flashing",
    "activeFrom" : "Apr 30, 2013 6:18:00 PM",
    "publiclyVisible" : true,
    "locationLat" : 14.589366803498653,
    "locationLon" : 121.03713870048522,
    "publicDescription" : ""
}, {
    "id" : 28010939,
    "type" : "trafficlight",
    "title" : "301 - Andalucia (A. Mendoza) / P. Campa - No Display",
    "activeFrom" : "Apr 30, 2013 6:00:00 PM",
    "publiclyVisible" : true,
    "locationLat" : 14.608034456366056,
    "locationLon" : 120.98599433898926,
    "publicDescription" : ""
} ...
]
```

I can parse ones that have an object and jsonArrays but this one has neither. How can i iterate through these and be able to store each information like the "id". I'm using the org.json library, or should i use a different one?

Comment: what do you mean by it has neither? `[` represents json array node and `{` represents json object node

Comment: @Raghunandan, but to be able to parse that i need a name right? like so `jsonFile.getJSONObject("string") or jsonFile.getJSONArray("string")` since it is empty how should i access them?

Comment: How do you get your json is it a string?

Comment: @Raghunandan, yes it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to parse try the below

```
[           // json array node
    {       // json object node
        "id": 28010942,      
        "type": "trafficlight",
```

To parse

```
   JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray("Myjsonstring");
   for(int i=0 ;i<jarray.length();i++)
   {
   JSONObject jb = (JSONObject)jarray.get(i); 
   String id = jb.getString("id");
   String type = jb.getString("type");
   // same for others title, activeform..
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think to create a jsonArray using the string immediately. Thank you very much!